# Regex contain match that should not match

Tags: regex, perl

Given this `;` delimited string

```
hap;; z
z ;d;hh 
 z;d;hh ;gfg;fdf ;ppp
ap;jj
lo mo;z
d;23
;;io;
b yio;b;12
 b 
a;b;bb;;;34
```

I am looking to get columns `$1 $2  $3` from any line that contains `ap` or `b` or `o m` in column 1

Using this regex

```
^(?:(.*?(?:ap|b|o m).*?)(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?(?:;([^\r\n;]*))?(?:;.*)?|.*)$
```

as shown in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRhpBg/1/) one can see that line 11 should not be matching, but it does.

Can not use negated character class to match the before and after sections of column 1, as far as I understand.

Any help making line 11, not match?

Comment: But there is no `ap` or `b` or `o m`  in column 1 on line 11 right?

Comment: Why do you have do this with regex? Why can't you simply define field separator to `;` and match the individual column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that match your data:

`^([^;\n]*(?:ap|b|o m)[^;]*);((?(1)[^;]*));?((?(1)[^;]*))$`

You can [see it in action](https://regex101.com/r/mRhpBg/4).

Answer (score 2):

You may consider this `perl` one-liner that works like `awk`:

```
perl -F';' -MEnglish -ne  'BEGIN {$OFS=";"} print $F[0],$F[1],$F[2] if $F[0] =~ /ap|b|o m/' file
```

An `awk` would be even more simpler:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} $1 ~ /ap|b|o m/{print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

```
hap;; z
ap;jj;
lo mo;z;
b yio;b;12
 b ;;
```